# How can i unbind radeon driver gracefully?

Tags: linux, kernel

I have igd and  ati graphics card on my pc. I use ubuntu as my OS.
After system boot, ati graphics card was bound to radeon driver.

I tried to unbind Radeon by typing "echo 0000:01:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/driver/radeon/unbind".
After I tried this, I saw this kernel error:

```
[  316.289664] Call Trace:
[  316.289665]  [<ffffffff8275c32c>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[  316.289667]  [<ffffffff8207022d>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[  316.289668]  [<ffffffff8207029c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
[  316.289669]  [<ffffffff82097d68>] ? check_preempt_curr+0x78/0xa0
[  316.289675]  [<ffffffffc0b26d52>] radeon_gart_unbind+0xd2/0xe0 [radeon]
[  316.289680]  [<ffffffffc0b23b4a>] radeon_ttm_backend_unbind+0x1a/0x20 [radeon]
[  316.289681]  [<ffffffffc0ae5fc7>] ttm_tt_unbind+0x27/0x40 [ttm]
[  316.289683]  [<ffffffffc0ae9928>] ttm_bo_move_ttm+0xd8/0x120 [ttm]
```

Can I even unbind the Radeon Driver, or will drm prevent this?

PS: I need radeon to exists after system boot and then unbind it afterwards, otherwise I could just put
radeon in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

Answer (score 1):

DRM does not support that. Thats unfortunate for you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no support from DRM. You can find good walkarounds, which offer a decent solution on this website [DRM support: Platform comparison - castLabs](https://castlabs.com/resources/drm-comparison/)